# How to disable camel case selection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings, camelcasing

Is it possible to disable support for camel case in the Eclipse text editor? I want the next word key binding to select the next word, not the next fragment of a word.

I'd given up on eclipse because the editor doesn't work like any other text editor on Mac OS X. But I'd really miss code-completion and am trying to make Eclipse to adapt to my conventions.

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: Thanks for asking this. You just saved me from finger and palm joint pains.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you mean this?

Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor: uncheck Smart caret positioning in Java names

Comment: In my version (with CDT / Momentics version), it was 'Smart caret positioning in identifiers' that I had to uncheck and it was naturally under C/C++ rather than Java (could not find it on my own with a name like that...). I was able to type 'caret' into the search box.

Comment: That works, but unfortunately, if you're using 'C/C++', there's no way to get the smart caret positioning feature to ignore underscores, at least not until this bug gets fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324316
Please upvote the bug. :)